# Vagrant не предлагает выбрать сетевой интерфейс

Tags: vagrant, bridge

Установил Vagrant на Windows 10, создал виртуалку через него, однако при выполнении команды "vagrant up" сначала виртуалка якобы запускается, а затем появляется сообщение "which interface should the network bridge to vagrant" с двуеточием и пустотой, без каких-либо пунктов выбора. гуглил вопрос, единственное более-менее понятное решение - это в Vagrantfile в строчке config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "хххххххх" на месте хххххх задать название сетевого интерфейса, однако я чего-только не пробовал - всё равно ничего не меняется... Может, я не правильно задаю название интерфейса? Буду благодарен помощи!

Answer (score 0):

В общем, проблема решена. Вернее, решена в обход. Изначально я делал настройку Vagrant в винде через bash-терминал cmder, в котором, собственно, и была проблема. Начал поднимать Vagrant через PowerShell - всё завелось с полуоборота.